# Build fails during make of OpenCV on Raspberry Pi with "segmentation fault" caused by "cc1plus"

Tags: opencv, cmake, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to make a build of OpenCV 4.0.0 on my Raspberry Pi 3B+, and keep running into this issue:

```
[ 83%] Building CXX object modules/stitching/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_stitching.dir/perf/opencl/perf_stitch.cpp.o

c++: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs> for instructions.
modules/stitching/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_stitching.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'modules/stitching/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_stitching.dir/perf/opencl/perf_stitch.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [modules/stitching/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_stitching.dir/perf/opencl/perf_stitch.cpp.o] Error 4
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:23142: recipe for target 'modules/stitching/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_stitching.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/stitching/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_stitching.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:162: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This is the make/build portion of the script I'm running:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
    -D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules \
    -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=~/.virtualenvs/py3cv4/bin/python \
    -D WITH_GSTREAMER=ON \
    -D WITH_FFMPEG=ON \
    -D WITH_OPENMP=ON \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..

echo ""
echo "======================="
echo "Building OpenCV..."
make -j4
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

I read somewhere that I should change the `make -j4` command to not use all four cores, because I'm running out of memory. I tried `make -j1`, but still got the same error at the same spot. I'm going to try again with just plain `make`, but delete all the pre-built stuff that's in there and start over from scratch to see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to entirely delete the build I had created and rebuild it with a single core instead of all four, as it was using up too much memory. I deleted my `/opencv/build/` directory and then did `make` with no `-j` command, and it worked fine. It took a really long time (5+ hours), but it did complete successfully. Now I just have to figure out why I can't `import cv2`...

Comment: I had to symlink `cv2.cpython-XXXXXX-linux-gnu.so` into my virtualenv under `~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/` I also renamed it `cv2.so`. You will probably, or might have done something similar.